# How to add an arrow (from on cell to other ) in excel using openxml c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

How do I add an arrow (straignConnectior) from one cell to another. Using Openxml in C#. I am only allowed to using Openxml.

The xml generated in drawing.html is different from the one which I directly draw on excel. I need to draw from on cell (for example A1) to another (B1).

I couldn't find any example on internet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using Xdr = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddArrowToFirstSheet("file path");
    }

    public static void AddArrowToFirstSheet(string excelFilePath)
    {
        // Open the spreadsheet document for editing
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelFilePath, true))
        {
            // Get the workbook part
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            // Get the first worksheet part
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

            // Create a drawings part for the worksheet if it doesn't exist
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.DrawingsPart drawingsPart;
            if (worksheetPart.DrawingsPart == null)
            {
                drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.DrawingsPart>();
            }
            else
            {
                drawingsPart = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart;
            }

            // Generate a unique relationship ID for the drawing
            string rId = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart);

            // Create the necessary elements for the drawing
            Xdr.WorksheetDrawing worksheetDrawing;
            if (drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing == null)
            {
                worksheetDrawing = new Xdr.WorksheetDrawing();
            }
            else
            {
                worksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing;
            }

            // Create an anchor for the arrow
            Xdr.TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = new Xdr.TwoCellAnchor();

            // Set the starting and ending positions for the arrow
            twoCellAnchor.FromMarker = new Xdr.FromMarker
            {
                ColumnId = new Xdr.ColumnId("1"),
                ColumnOffset = new Xdr.ColumnOffset("0"),
                RowId = new Xdr.RowId("1"),
                RowOffset = new Xdr.RowOffset("0")
            };

            twoCellAnchor.ToMarker = new Xdr.ToMarker
            {
                ColumnId = new Xdr.ColumnId("1"),
                ColumnOffset = new Xdr.ColumnOffset("0"),
                RowId = new Xdr.RowId("2"),
                RowOffset = new Xdr.RowOffset("0")
            };

            // Create the shape and its properties
            A.Shape shape = GenerateArrowShape();

            // Create the non-visual shape properties
            A.NonVisualShapeProperties nonVisualShapeProperties = new A.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                new A.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = 1U, Name = "Arrow1" },
                new A.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties());

            // Add elements to the drawing
            //A.Shape xdrShape = new A.Shape
            //{
            //    NonVisualShapeProperties = nonVisualShapeProperties,
            //    ShapeProperties = shape.ShapeProperties,
            //    //TextBody = shape.TextBody
            //};

            //twoCellAnchor.Append(xdrShape);
            worksheetDrawing.Append(twoCellAnchor);

            // Add the drawing to the drawings part
            drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = worksheetDrawing;

            // Save changes to the spreadsheet document
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }

    // Function to generate an arrow shape
    private static A.Shape GenerateArrowShape()
    {
        A.Shape shape = new A.Shape();
        A.ShapeProperties shapeProperties = new A.ShapeProperties();

        A.Outline outline = new A.Outline(new A.NoFill());
        shapeProperties.Append(outline);

        A.PresetGeometry presetGeometry = new A.PresetGeometry { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.StraightConnector1 };
        shapeProperties.Append(presetGeometry);

        A.SolidFill solidFill = new A.SolidFill();
        A.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex = new A.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "FF0000" }; // Red color
        solidFill.Append(rgbColorModelHex);

        shapeProperties.Append(solidFill);
        shape.Append(shapeProperties);

        return shape;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you want to achieve? Perhaps screenshots of what you want to achieve and what is being rendered.